# Trashes in copied std::list

Tags: c++, list, stl, gdb, circular-list

I have graph class that looks like:

```
class Graph {
  public:
    typedef unsigned int size_type;
    typedef std::list<size_type> Neighbours;

  protected:
    size_type m_nodes_count, m_edges_count;

  public:
    Graph(size_type nodes_count = 0) :
      m_nodes_count(nodes_count), m_edges_count(0) {}

    virtual bool is_edge(size_type from, size_type to) = 0;
    virtual Neighbours neighbours(size_type node) = 0;

    virtual Graph& add_edge(size_type from, size_type to) = 0;
    virtual void delete_edge(size_type from, size_type to) = 0;

    size_type nodes_count() { return m_nodes_count; }
    size_type edges_count() { return m_edges_count; }

    virtual ~Graph() {}
};

class AdjList : public Graph {
  private:
    typedef std::list<size_type> Row;
    std::vector<Row> m_list;

  public:
    AdjList(size_type nodes_count) : Graph(nodes_count) {
      m_list.resize(nodes_count);
    }

    AdjList(const AdjList& g) : AdjList(g.m_nodes_count) {
      for (int i = 0; i < nodes_count(); i++)
        std::copy(g.m_list[i].begin(), g.m_list[i].end(), std::back_inserter(m_list[i]));
    }

    virtual bool is_edge(size_type from, size_type to) override {
      return std::find(m_list[from].begin(), m_list[from].end(), to) != m_list[from].end();
    }

    virtual Graph& add_edge(size_type from, size_type to) override {
      if (!is_edge(from, to) && !is_edge(to, from)) {
        m_list[from].push_back(to);
        m_list[to].push_back(from);
        m_edges_count++;
      }

      return *this;
    }

    virtual void delete_edge(size_type from, size_type to) override {
      m_list[from].remove(to);
      m_list[to].remove(to);
      m_edges_count--;
    }

    virtual Neighbours neighbours(size_type node) {
      return m_list[node];
    }
};
```

but when I try to get `graph.neighbours(v)` I get big amount of trash in it:

```
(gdb) p graph
$1 = {<Graph> = {_vptr.Graph = 0x406210 <vtable for AdjList+16>, m_nodes_count = 3, m_edges_count = 3}, m_list = std::vector of length 3, capacity 3 = {std::list = {[0]
 = 2, [1] = 1},
    std::list = {[0] = 0, [1] = 2}, std::list = {[0] = 0, [1] = 1}}}
(gdb) p graph.neighbours(0)
$2 = std::list = {[0] = 2, [1] = 1, [2] = 4294956560, [3] = 2, [4] = 1,
  [5] = 4294956560, [6] = 2, [7] = 1, [8] = 4294956560, [9] = 2, [10] = 1,
  [11] = 4294956560, [12] = 2, [13] = 1, [14] = 4294956560, [15] = 2,
  [16] = 1, [17] = 4294956560, [18] = 2, [19] = 1, [20] = 4294956560,
  [21] = 2, [22] = 1, [23] = 4294956560, [24] = 2, [25] = 1,...
```

How to fix that?

Comment: What is `Neighbours` (it appears to be a typedef, but want to be sure)

Comment: Also, is it possible it's something unusual with the gdb pretty printer?  If you run code that assigns the result to a local variable, does it produce the same result?

Comment: Then it print good. Thanks. But it still dosn't solve that what I'm working at :/ But thanks.

Comment: Well, if it prints correctly after assignment, it might be a bug in GDB, where the return value's destructor is being executed prior to the print, causing garbage data.

Comment: could you give the code that initializes your graph as well? right up to the `g.neighbours(0)` call, please

Comment: an output of `p/r graph.neighbours(0)` (that is, bypassing the python stuff) could be useful too, to see the stored size member of the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gdb` is probably getting confused by an **implementation detail** the `std::list`. E.g. the old [SGI STL `list`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_list.h) was implemented as a **circular list**. Inside the `list` object, there is only a singly `_List_node<_Tp>` pointer called `_M_node`. The constructor puts the internal `_M_next` pointer of the final node element equal to `_M_node` itself.

The reason Standard Library implementations of `std::list` use this circular implementation is to avoid special cases for the final element (e.g. they could also use a a sentinel element with a `nullptr` next pointer). Matt Austern has a nice [ACCU presentation](http://www.accu-usa.org/Slides/SinglyLinkedLists.ppt) about this (but the link is currently to a corrupted file, see [archived version here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090618135116/http://www.accu-usa.org/Slides/SinglyLinkedLists.ppt)).

This circular implementation explains why your `gdb` output for `g.neighbors()` has the repeating pattern of `[0] = 2, [1] = 1, [2] = 4294956560, /* etcetera */`. The value 4294956560 is simply the memory address of the internal `_M_node` variable of your `std::list`, so if `gdb` only does simnple pointer chasing, it will get confused. Notice that it is less than `2^32`, i.e. you are probably compiling this for 32-bits.

You should probably verify this in your own `<list>` header of the Standard Library on your system. A bug report for `gdb` might also be in order.

Comment: Which makes me wonder why if this is the case, the above output of std::list instances works...

Comment: who knows, the debugger might have a limit to how many elements it will show and truncate.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is on the copy constructor, just do this:

```
AdjList(const AdjList& g) : AdjList(g.m_nodes_count) {
    m_list = g.m_list ; 
}
```

The `operator=()` method should create a new `Vector<Row>` with the same nodes that `g.m_list` has.