# std::map::insert infinite loop for incorrect value_type

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

I've recently come across a really stupid bug in some code I just wrote. After spending some time looking through a debugger, I discovered something that I find quite strange. Consider the following incorrect, but trivial code.

```
#include <map>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::map<int, std::list<int> > myMap;
    // infinite loop, should be std::pair<int, std::list<int> >
    myMap.insert(std::pair<int, int>(4, 500000)); 

    return 0;
}
```

As the comment indicates, the `insert` statement causes the program to enter an infinite loop. The cause of this is quite obvious, I've passed in a `std::pair<int, int>` object instead of `std::pair<int, std::list<int>>`. Unfortunately, this code compiles perfectly fine in both gcc and MSVC10. I would expect the compiler to reject this code because the types obviously don't match, but it didn't. Would anyone care to explain why?

edit: It appears to work fine in gcc (the site I used didn't work correctly), but MSVC10 still accepts it.

edit again: I believe the crash was caused by the fact that, in my original code, the insertion was inserting like:

`myMap.insert(std::pair<int, int>(4, id))` where `id` could potentially be very large. It never raised any memory exceptions, but I guess it was spending a lot of time allocating it (without failing), which is why it appeared to loop. So, it seems that MSVC is happy to do the implicit conversion to `std::list`, but gcc isn't. This is confusing, according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/list/ the constructors for `std::list` are all marked as `explicit`. Looks like a bug is MSVC10, MSVC11 rejects this code (as it should).

Comment: http://ideone.com/sWAK50

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I tried it at http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php and it compiled fine, but execution didn't finish.

Comment: Weird, what gcc version are you using? I get an error: `error: no matching function for call to 'map<int, list<int> >::insert(pair<int, int>)'`

Comment: @user1520427: Maybe compilation on that site didnt finish...

Comment: maybe the debugger [chokes on a circular linked-list implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17154274/819272)?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Hmm, that could be right. It says it's using gcc 4.7.2, which is what Luchian's site uses, so I'd expect it to reject it too. But MSVC10 definitely didn't give me any errors.

Comment: @user1520427: Maybe it converts the int to the list (since that has an implicit ctor taking an int)? Have you tried looking at the size of the inserted list?

Comment: @TemplateRex: what debugger?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Aren't relevant constructors to list all explicit though?

Comment: @user1520427: well, msvc even accepts non-const references to temporaries...

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yeah, I guess it's a bug with the compiler :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried compiling in visual studio 2010

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
```

It compiled, but did *not* enter an infinite loop. Instead it did the following...

```
std::map<int, std::list<int> > myMap;

myMap.insert(std::pair<int, int>(4, 5)); // An implicit cast???

std::cout << "mymap now contains " << myMap.size() << " elements.\n";
std::cout << "myMap[4] size is " << myMap[4].size() << '\n';

sel = myMap[4].begin();
end = myMap[4].end();
for(; sel != end; ++sel)
    std::cout << *sel << ", ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

outputs the following

```
mymap now contains 1 elements.
myMap[4] size is 5
0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

So, i think the reason this is working is that the list is being created using the following default constructor:

```
explicit list (size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(),
               const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

So it is creating for you, 4 mapping to a list of 5 elements, each filled with value_type().

My guess is that *somehow* the msvc compiler is casting `std::pair<int, int>` to `std::pair<int, std::list<int>>` using the above constructor for list...

That goes some way to answering why it compiles without complaining... but it doesn't explain your infinite loop... don't know what to say about that :)

Comment: I updated my code, the loop is caused by 5 not actually being 5, it can be a rather large number. So I guess the conversion takes awhile to do (hence the perceived loop). I've updated my question, but I'm still confused because that constructor is explicit.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure about it. The list can be constructed with a `size_type` so I think it is a valid explicit creation of the list, i.e. the parameter to the constructor is the right type - We can do `std::list<int>(100)` for example... but that's creating a list... this is a cast, so as you say, should it implicitly create the list?! Probably not, but it does appear to be doing so :-S

Comment: It's my understanding that `explicit` means it cannot do any conversions to `std::list` - you'd need to explicitly call the constructor. I've tried to compile this code with MSVC11 and it gets rejected, so I guess it's a bug in the 2010 compiler.

Comment: My comment's not very clear... I meant if you called the constructor directly it would be fine but questioned whether you should be able to cast it, which you're right, you shouldn't be able to do if it is marked as `explicit`. Just trying to search for any known problems with this and msvc

Comment: Could be worth leaving some feedback with MS... perhaps someone there will know why the compiler is doing this? https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/